# Laravel updating column with relation

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the model with activation tokens:

```
class ActivationToken extends Model
{
    public function user() : BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

in Activation controller, i have the $token object. So, I can check with the user is attached to this token:
`$token->user;` the question is how can I update an `is_active column` in my user table?

`$token->user->is_active = true;` How can i save it?

Comment: Have you tried `User::where('id',$token->user->id)->update(['is_active'=>true]);` ?

Comment: @Shubhampokhriyal this working. $token->user->update(['is_active' => true]) thx